# identifier "test" is undefined; What does this mean in this context

Tags: c++

I am writing a weather station for a raspberry. I'm always getting the error message identifier "test" is undefined.

I've already tried to use no external class with a little example and this works perfectly. Now I'm trying to create an object test, but this doesn't work. I am always getting the error message:

E0020   identifier "test" is undefined

main.cpp:

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

include "MeasureWeather.h"
int main(void)
{
    MeasureWeather test;

while (1)
{
    test._setSensorPin(DHT_PIN);
}

return 0;
}
```

MeasureWeather.h:

```
#ifndef MeasureWeather
#define MeasureWeather

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>
class MeasureWeather
{
public:

//setter for sensor pin
void _setSensorPin(uint8_t pin);


private:
    uint8_t sensorPin;
};

#endif // !MeasureWeather
```

MeasureWeather.cpp:

```
include "MeasureWeather.h"

void MeasureWeather::setSensorPin(uint8_t pin) 
{   
    _sensorPin = pin; 
}
```

I hope somebody can help me with my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Did you forget to include `MeasureWeather.h` into `Main.cpp`?

Comment: Are this the real code? Im asking that because `actTempHum()` is not defined, neither `_setSensorPin(..) nor is `_sensorPin`

Comment: No i included MeasureWeather.h into my Main.cpp so this isn't the issue.

Comment: Please create a [mre] in a single source file.

Comment: it isn't the real code it is only a snippet of it

Comment: Hmm... does `MeasureWeather.h` include `<cstdint>` (or `<stdint.h>`, but the former is preferable), out of curiosity?

Comment: You have `include` where you need `#include`. Your header file has a `#endif` with no matching `#if` or `#ifdef`. You need to copy-and-paste the entirety of each of your source files into your question.

Comment: @KeithThompson sorry i forgot this. now it is in the code snippet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have this at the top of your header file, as part of the include guard:

```
#define MeasureWeather
```

`MeasureWeather` is the name of your class. By defining it as a macro, you hide the class name. Thus the line

```
MeasureWeather test;
```

expands to

```
 test;
```

which would be a reference to something called `test`, not a declaration.

Use a different identifier for your `#include` guard.

Comment: A lovely example of "see, this is why you need an MCVE in your question."